# Problem When Transcribing Greek HTML Letters to LaTex

Tags: python, html, string, latex

I have the following HTML string:

```
s = "I have : <i><λv<sub>1</sub>,w> + <v<sub>2</sub>,w></i>"
```

Now, I would like to convert it to LaTex. To do so, I am using [pypandoc](https://pypi.org/project/pypandoc/).

```
import pypandoc
text = pypandoc.convert_text(s,'latex', format = "html", extra_args = ['--wrap=preserve'] )
text
```

I get:

```
I have : \emph{1,w\textgreater{} + 2,w\textgreater{}}\r\n
```

which in readable LaTex becomes:

[image]

**Anyone knows how to fix it ?**

Funny enough, if I just type the above string into Stackoverflow, I get the correct output:

I have : *<λv<sub>1</sub>,w> + 2,w>*

I am interested in a general solution, not a manual fix for this particular example, since I have massive amounts of html text that I need to transcribe.

How can I achieve this for LaTex ?

Answer (score 0):

Doing some Quantum homework? Try using the symbol escapes built into LaTeX. For example, \lambda.

```
I have : \langle \lambda v\sub{1}, w \rangle + \langle 2, w \rangle
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I need a more general fix. I have massive amounts of html fix, which I need to transcribe, so I cannot do it manually, as you suggest.